# why is useEffect not updating the value after the api call?

Tags: reactjs, fetch, react-hooks

im calling an api that does a fetch , but when using setHotSalesArray, the hotSalesArray is empty after useEffect Finishes

i have tried calling another function sending the data, also tried putting the data inside a variable to try and update it that way

here is the part im having trouble with

```
const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(true);
  const [hotSalesArray, setHotSales] = useState({});

  useEffect(()=>{
    let infoData;
    API.getToken().then(
      (data) =>API.getHotSale(data).then(info => (
        infoData = info,
        setHotSales(infoData),
        setIsActive(false),
        console.log(hotSalesArray,info, infoData)
        ),
      )
    )
  },[])
```

this is what i get on the console :

```sh
{} {hotsales: Array(1)} {hotsales: Array(1)}
```

and the result im expecting is this:

```sh
{hotsales: Array(1)} {hotsales: Array(1)} {hotsales: Array(1)}
```

Update:

so i learned that i need a re-render to happen so i can have my new value inside the variable, my problem is i have this in my return

````
         <div className="hotSalesContainer">
         <h1 className="activitiesLabelHot">
              Ventas Calientes
          </h1>
            {hotSales}
               { hotSales !== undefined ? hotSales.map((hotsale,index) => <PropertyElement data={hotsales}  key={index.toString()} /> ) : ""}
          </div>```

so i need the object hotSales to have something before i return that, i used to do this call before with componentWillMount, but im trying to learn how to use hooks
````

Comment: Hi @linkshady welcome to Stackoverflow! I see a syntax error in `API.getHotSale(data).then(...)`. `(` after the `=>` should be `{` as well as the closing bracket. That could just be a typo in your code example, but thought I should mention.

Comment: @bflemi3, it's operator coma. it's legit but I agree looks really [confusing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56700639/rxjs-scan-with-so-many-comas-inside-its-function-body)

Comment: when you call `useState` state will be updated only on next render. it's expected behavior. see https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/#each-render-has-its-own-effects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do `console.log(hotSalesArray, info, infoData)`, `hotSalesArray` will have the value of the current render, which is `{}` (the initial value). It won't be until a re-render occurs that `hotSalesArray` will have the value of `{ hotsales: [...] }`, but you won't see that in the console because you're only logging when the response comes back from your API.

Add a console log directly in the render and you'll see.

---

I fixed the syntax errors and did some cleanup. Besides the syntax errors though, you had the right idea. This could be improved upon with [`useReducer`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer) perhaps, but I didn't want to overcomplicate the answer :)

```
const MyComponent = () => {
    const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(true);
    const [hotSales, setHotSales] = useState({});

    useEffect(
      () => {
        API.getToken()
          .then(data => API.getHotSale(data))
          .then(info => {
            setHotSales(info);
            setIsActive(false);
          })
      },
      []
    );

    const { hotsales = [] } = hotSales;
    return ( 
        <div className='hotSalesContainer'> 
            <h1 className='activitiesLabelHot'>Ventas Calientes</h1> 

            { hotsales.length && 
                hotsales.map((sale, index) => 
                    <PropertyElement data={sale} key={index} /> 
                )
            } 
        </div>
    )   
}
```

Comment: thanks @bflemi3, but i still get hotSalesArray as a blank object, thanks a lot for the code clean up tho, a lot easier to read hehehe, could you elaborate on your useReducer comment please?

Comment: I see. `hotSalesArray` will have the initial value of `{}` because you initialize the state with `useState({})` that's why you're seeing an empty object for the first item in the `console.log`. Change it to `useState('hi')` and you'll see `hi` as the first item in the console log.

Comment: You're expectations are wrong, your actions aren't :) I updated my example to better match the expected data type that will be returned by your api.

Comment: i understand that but i want hotSalesArray to be populated by the response of the api API.getHotsale.

just saw your question on the update, the data that i get from hotsale is an object, i didnt change the initial name i gave to the variable, but your right hotSales is more appropriate

Comment: My example will set `hotSales` to whatever gets returned from `API.getHotSale`. Maybe nothing is being returned.

Comment: but when i add info into the console.log i do get  that theres an object inside of the variable ```info```

Comment: I misunderstood your question, my apologies. I updated my answer.

Comment: no problem, i understand your answer completly, now my question is.....how do i trigger the reload, the problem is in the return part of my code i have this:

```    return (

         <div className='hotSalesContainer'>
         <h1 className='activitiesLabelHot'>
              Ventas Calientes
          </h1>
              {/* { hotSales !== undefined ? hotSales.map((hotsale,index) => <PropertyElement data={hotsales}  key={index.toString()} /> ) : ''} */}
          </div>``` so i need the hotSales object to have something on first render

Comment: See updated answer. I'm heading out for the weekend. I'll check back on Monday.